# Visual Studio 2012 weird colored tab mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm not sure how I got my Visual Studio 2012 in this mode, but all of a sudden my tabs started to be colored.  Some are different colored.  I also started constantly getting asked, "You have mixed tabs and spaces, Fix this?"  And even though I answer, Don't Ask Again, it constantly asks me.  I included a picture of the tabs.  I'm using the dark colored VS view.  Does anyone know why this happened and how I can get out of this mode?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Poductivity Power Tools installed (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)? If so, they have the functionality to colorize tabs according to the project they belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you have installed *Poductivity Power Tools* (obvious guess) you can enable/disable the coloring-option here:

[image]

And here you can config the colors:

[image]

---

> "You have mixed tabs and spaces, Fix this?"

Can be disabled via this option:

[image]